# How to read and process each line of a large text file asynchronously in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a large file (4 million lines, ~120-160 characters each line) that I want to process (replace some patterns in every line), result to be written to another file.

Maybe I am wrong, but if I use `readLines()` the function call will complete when the whole input file has been read into memory. Only then I can process each line and write the result to the output file. However, what I want is to process each line as soon as it becomes available and write the line result to the output file immediately, effectively running read and write in quasi-parallel manner and keeping memory footprint low at the same time.

Does the script below do bulk read, or does it actually do what I want?

```js
const { open, readdir } = require ('node:fs/promises')
const srcDir = process.argv[2]
const outDir = path.join( srcDir, 'csv' );

readdir( srcDir ).then( scanFiles )

function scanFiles(files) {
  for (const f of files) {
    if (f.match(/^\d+_\d+\.csv$/)) {
      convertFile(f)
    }
  }
}

async function convertFile(filename) {
  const input = await open(path.join(srcDir, filename))
  const out = await open(path.join(outDir, filename), 'w')
  for await (let line of input.readLines()) {
    await out.write( line.replace(/;/g, ',')+'\n' )
  }
  await out.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when I started this on a directory with 32 files of varying sizes (3 KB to 100+ MB), I could see in process monitor that memory consumption rose only by roughly 100 MB while conversion of all 32 files effectively ran in parallel.

Issue closed ;-)